# CLLocation found nil after using CLLocationManagerDelegate

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

I want to get `longitude` and `latitude`, and I add `CLLocationManagerDelegate` in the controller.

here is my code

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()


func getWeatherInformation(){
    var currentLocation: CLLocation!

    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    if( CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse ||
        CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() ==  .authorizedAlways){
        currentLocation = locationManager.location
    }

    let longitude = "\(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)"
    let latitude = "\(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)"
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    getWeatherInformation()

}
```

}

I also add location items in the `info.plist`, please see the screenshot

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPV6q.png)

The problem is both `longitude` and `latitude`, found nil after run the app and crash it. 
What the problem come from?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Location maybe not available right after request. 
Please implement delegate function

```
optional func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,  didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
```

to get location.